# Navigate form fields with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, forms, codeigniter, input

I have a form with *New Row* function script. Then i added a new script *navigate form fields* from this site [Form Navigation script](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/navigate-form-fields-with-arrow-keys.html)

[image]

The navigate script is works fine **only** in *Row 1*. I can move between fields (*right to left, left to right*) using the arrow keys. If i add new row, i can move to Row 2 (*up to down*), but i cannot move back to *Row 1* (*down to up*) and also i cannot move between fields in *Row 2* (*right to left, left to right*). And if i add new row again, *Row 3* the *navigate script* doesn't work at all, i only can move from *Row 1* to *Row 2* (*up to down*), *Row 2* to *Row 3* not working.

[image]

Here are my code, **New Row** script:

```
var row_id = 1;
function addRow(tableID) {            
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    row.id = 'id' + row_id;
    row_id++;
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
       var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
       newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
       //alert(newcell.childNodes);
       switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
             case "text":
                  newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
             break;
             case "checkbox":
                  newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
             break;
             case "select-one":
                  newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
             break;
             case "select":
                  newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
             break;
             default:
                  newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
             break;
        }               
    }
}
```

Form code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped sticky-header">
[....]
<tbody id="dataTable2">
   <?php if(!isset($dtdetail)) {;
         if(isset($message)) {

         for ($i=0; $i < $jmldtl; $i++) { ?>

         <tr>                                                                                                
            <td>
               <input type="text" name="tp_sal[]" id="tp_sal" size="5" value="<?php echo set_value('tp_sal['.$i.']'); ?>"/></td>
            <td>
               <input type="text" name="r_tpc_1[]" id="r_tpc_1" size="5" value="<?php echo set_value('r_tpc_1['.$i.']'); ?>"/></td>
            <td>
               <input type="text" name="r_tpc_2[]" id="r_tpc_2" size="10" value="<?php echo set_value('r_tpc_2['.$i.']'); ?>"/></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="r_tpc_3[]" id="r_tpc_3" size="15" value="<?php echo set_value('r_tpc_3['.$i.']'); ?>"/></td>  
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="r_etr_1[]" id="r_etr_1" size="13" value="<?php echo set_value('r_etr_1['.$i.']'); ?>"/></td>                                                  
        </tr>
        <?php } } else { ?>
        <tr>                                                                                               
           <td>
              <input type="text" name="tp_sal[]" id="tp_sal" size="5" value="<?php $a=set_value('tp_sal'); echo $a; ?>"/></td>
           <td>
              <input type="text" name="r_tpc_1[]" id="r_tpc_1" size="5" value="<?php $a=set_value('r_tpc_1'); echo $a; ?>"/></td>
           <td>
              <input type="text" name="r_tpc_2[]" id="r_tpc_2" size="10" value="<?php $a=set_value('r_tpc_2'); echo $a; ?>"/></td>
           <td>
              <input type="text" name="r_tpc_3[]" id="r_tpc_3" size="15" value="<?php $a=set_value('r_tpc_3'); echo $a; ?>"/></td>  
           <td>
              <input type="text" name="r_etr_1[]" id="r_etr_1" size="13" value="<?php $a=set_value('r_etr_1'); echo $a; ?>"/></td>                                                  
       </tr>
 <?php } } else {
     foreach($dtdetail as $detail) { ?>
       <tr>                                                    
          <td>
             <input type="text" name="tp_sal[]" id="tp_sal" size="5" value="<?php echo $detail->tp_sal; ?>"/></td>
          <td>
             <input type="text" name="r_tpc_1[]" id="r_tpc_1" size="5" value="<?php echo $detail->r_tpc_1; ?>"/></td>
          <td>
             <input type="text" name="r_tpc_2[]" id="r_tpc_2" size="10" value="<?php echo $detail->r_tpc_2; ?>"/></td>
          <td>
             <input type="text" name="r_tpc_3[]" id="r_tpc_3" size="15" value="<?php echo $detail->r_tpc_3; ?>"/></td>  
          <td>
             <input type="text" name="r_etr_1[]" id="r_etr_1" size="13" value="<?php echo $detail->r_etr_1; ?>"/></td>                                               
      </tr>
<?php } } ?>
</tbody>
<tfoot class="bg-primary">
    <tr>
       <td colspan="31" align="center">
           <?php if(!isset($dtdetail)) {?>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" onClick="addRow('dataTable2')">New Row</button>
           <?php } else { ?>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" onClick="addRow('dataTable2')">New Row</button>
           <?php } ?>
       </td>
   </tr>
</tfoot>
[.....]

<?php
$this->load->view('template/js2');
?>
```

and the **Form Navigation** script in **js2** file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /*!
* formNavigation
* Copyright 2013 Ole Bjørn Michelsen <http://ole.michelsen.dk/>
* MIT license
*/
(function ($) {
    $.fn.formNavigation = function () {
        $(this).each(function () {
            $(this).find('input').on('keyup', function(e) {
                switch (e.which) {
                    case 39:
                        $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').focus(); break;
                    case 37:
                        $(this).closest('td').prev().find('input').focus(); break;
                    case 40:
                        $(this).closest('tr').next().children().eq($(this).closest('td').index()).find('input').focus(); break;
                    case 38:
                        $(this).closest('tr').prev().children().eq($(this).closest('td').index()).find('input').focus(); break;
                }
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.table').formNavigation();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What if the user wants to move within the string in a textbox? I'm afraid that this is bad design from accessibility perspective.

Comment: Hmm, please give your suggestions, what design should i make ? Oh btw, if you know how do i make my code work, please tell me the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem

This is happening because the navigation script only applies to the rows in the table **at the time which it is ran**. So, the form navigation script is run on the document ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.table').formNavigation();
});
```

This event occurs when the HTML structure of the page is fully loaded, which is **before** the addRow() function is ever called. When the addRow() function gets called, it adds a new row, but this new row does not have the form navigation event handlers applied to it.

## Solution

To remedy this problem, add `$(row).formNavigation();` to the end of your addRow() function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, the script already worked by your solution.

Comment: hi @jon-anderson i have a new similar problem, still getting trouble with _addRow()_ function and i hope you can help me. I've created a new script _getWarning()_ this script is used for text fields background color validation, [getWarning function](http://pastebin.com/fX67mVnH). The specifications only works in **Row 1**, if i fill in a data in _Row 1_ with spec number 1, the script execute correctly, but if i add a new row, the _Row 2_ and fill in a data with spec number 2 with the text field that already have "finish" string, the script always executed spec number 1